# C# BHO: Cause internet explorer to close and reopen tab

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, bho

I am developing a BHO in C# to respond to the click event of a custom button added to the IE's toolbar and also catching the OnBeforeNavigate2 event.

Interfaces used are IOleCommandTarget::QueryStatus to get click event and IObjectWithSite::OnBeforeNavigate2.

IObjectWithSite part works fine.

While debugging, when I clicked on my extension button. It calls constructor of BHO then SetSite method and after the execution of SetSite program exits and following error is shown in IE.

[image]

The same BHO was working fine in two other OS(Win 7 & Win 8.1). But now it worked fine on my one development machine only i.e Windows 10, but on other all OS it gives the error.

So, far OS checked are Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.
 I have looked through the output windows while debugging. It shows

> 'iexplore.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'iexplore.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SNX_Protection_Bho\v4.0_1.0.0.0__d8c924c8b1b10d5d\SNX_Protection_Bho.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'iexplore.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'iexplore.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> The thread 0x28f4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[13068] iexplore.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you please inform us which OS you are using for making this test and on which OS your tests run successfully? Try to make similar IE settings as other OS. If the issue persists then try to reset the IE browser. Try to check for the latest Windows updates and installed them. An above-mentioned error may occur in various situations. We may need more information about your BHO extension to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have updated the question also I tried it on new machines

Comment: Does anything got changed or updated on those machines where your BHO shows the error? Did you modify something in your code after that it stopped working on those two machines?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT after too much searching I decided to recode, and after that it looks like there was an issue with the implementation of IOleCommandTarget interface

Comment: Do you mean that issue resolved with the new code? If yes, I suggest you share the solution as an answer and mark that answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.